# Fetch rejects promise on 404 responses instead of resolving with 404 status

Tags: cors, fetch-api, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm trying to figure out how to process failed http responses in the fetch example in [reason-react-example](https://github.com/reasonml-community/reason-react-example/blob/master/src/fetch/FetchExample.re) repo.

The following was my first idea (tinkering with the url):

```
Js.Promise.(
          Fetch.fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list")
          |> then_(res => {
               let ok = Fetch.Response.ok(res);
               ok ?
                 Fetch.Response.json(res) :
                 Js.Exn.raiseError(Fetch.Response.statusText(res));
             })
          |> then_(json =>
               json
               |> Decode.dogs
               |> (dogs => self.send(DogsFetched(dogs)))
               |> resolve
             )
          |> catch(err => {
               Js.log(err);
               [%bs.raw {| console.log(err.response) |}]
               Js.Promise.resolve(self.send(DogsFailedToFetch));
             })
          |> ignore
        );
```

It's not working as I hoped. It turns out `Fetch` rejects right away when the HTTP request fails with 404 for instance, which I didn't expect since it's not how the browser fetch API works. Moreover, when `err` is logged it's `TypeError: Failed to fetch` and the `err.response` property is undefined.

My question is: how to process the error to get the status code and status text for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is CORS. The server you're using will include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header with `2xx` responses, but not with `404` responses. So apparently you're only allowed to read successful responses from this server.

You should get some additional warnings or errors in the console that tells you something like:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/listio. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

or

> [Error] Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (listio, line 0)
>
> [Error] Fetch API cannot load https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/listio. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You can fix this, at least when just testing, by using `no-cors` mode instead. With `bs-fetch` you'd do:

```
Fetch.fetchWithInit(url, Fetch.RequestInit.make(~mode=Fetch.NoCORS, ()))
```

Comment: Pay attention to glennsl's **at least when just testing** bit! Otherwise this will come back to bite you when you move to Production. Just an FYI :)